# change image after timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have following code

```
   <div class="caption" style=" position:absolute; margin-top:0px">
   <img src="caption/img1.png" />
   </div>


 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){     
setTimeout(function() {
$('div.caption').fadeOut('slow');
$('div.caption').fadeIn();
}, 1000);

});
```

but this work only once, what i want to do is
after every 1000ms function should run and change image in div "caption" 
i have image series and i can put their names in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` takes the same arguments as `setTimeout` but it executes the function every n milliseconds, as specified. [see more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536749(VS.85).aspx)